# Upload files to windows azure drive from desktop application

Tags: azure, azure-storage

How can i upload files to windows azure drive from a desktop application without mounting the drive in the local machine?

Comment: mount it on an azure machine, and copy the files up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload your file to an app running in Windows Azure (on a Web or Worker Role), which can then write it to the Windows Azure Drive. Alternatively, if you don't want any app running in Windows Azure, you can directly upload it to a blob instead of an Azure Drive.

You cannot access a Windows Azure drive from a desktop app, nor can you access one from the compute emulator, unless you mount the drive in Emulator Storage.  (more info [here](http://preview.library.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433135.aspx) on mounting a drive from the emulator).

Comment: I would also clarify "mount" here in context of emulator.  It is not a true mount in any sense of the word.  It is a directory on disk that has a drive letter assigned to it (not a VHD).  The cloud does an honest to goodness "mount a VHD", while the emulator pretends to mount something.  You can see for yourself if you open the emulator and select File > Open Azure Drive Folder in Explorer.